# Как стилизовать данные элементы в WP?

Tags: wordpress

Создал новый post type, где добавляю товары. И они выводится. Как мне сделать следующее. Есть страница, где выводится список товаров и при клике открывается карточка товара. Это похоже на стандартную функцию WP. Т.е пост, и есть страница со всеми постами и при клике на пост открывается он полностью. Так вот где мне создать структуру для Preview Product и самого продукта.

P.s Юзаю фреймворк Alethemes, может кто знаком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно ознакомиться с иерархией шаблонов WP. Так как вы используете пост тайп product, шаблон вывода поста single-product.php

[иерархия шаблонов WP](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)